# a shadow appear below material button after setting background color tint in android

Tags: android, user-interface, material-design

I'm using the new **material component** like **MaterialButton** and **MaterialCardView**.
in my project, I need to change the material button `tintBackground` programmatically.
so I use `setBackgroundTintList` method to change the tint background color.

```
btnOk.setBackgroundTintList(ColorStateList.valueOf(Color.parseColor("#20" + colorAccept)));  
btnOk.setTextColor(Color.parseColor("#" + colorAccept));
```

as you can see I'm setting a transparent color to my material button.

---

I run my app in android **KitKat** and there was no problem as you can see in this picture.

[image: KitKat OutPut]

but in Android Marshmallow, the material button Appearance changes and a shadow appear below the material button like below picture.

[image: Marshmallow OutPut]

I try some other code but none of them works.

- first code

using below code does not change the tint background color of the button in android marshmallow.

```
ColorStateList colorOk = new ColorStateList(
                new int[][]{
                        new int[]{R.attr.buttonTint}
                },
                new int[] {
                        Color.parseColor("#20" + colorAccept)
                });
```

- second code

this code works just in KitKat and a shadow appears again in Marshmallow!

```
Drawable buttonDrawable = button.getBackground();
buttonDrawable = DrawableCompat.wrap(buttonDrawable);
//the color is a direct color int and not a color resource
DrawableCompat.setTint(buttonDrawable, Color.RED);
button.setBackground(buttonDrawable);
```

what is the problem that this shadow is showing in the newer API?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

this shadow appears in devices that use **API version 21** or **higher**.
adding the below **attribute** in the **XML** file make the button without shadow.

```
android:stateListAnimator="@null"
```

> attribute **stateListAnimator** is only used in **API version 21 or higher**

Answer (score 0):

Try setting `elevation`

```
setElevation(float elevation)

MaterialButton materialButton =findViewById(R.id.buttonid);
materialButton.setElevation(0.0f);
```

Comment: thanks for your answer but it does not work and shadow is showing :(